# How do I manage this form in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm building an online store and I'm creating a form where the user will select an option and the option's price will be added to the total price

```
class SingleProduct extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
  
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var products = this.props.products.products;
      
         var ID = this.props.router.location.pathname.slice(9, 100)
      
            var productArray = this.props.products.products.data.filter(function(product) {
              return product.id === ID;
            })
            
            var product = productArray[0];
      var addToCart = (id, options) => {
        this.props.dispatch((dispatch) => {
            
            if(this.props.value == 'select'){
                this.props.product.options = 0;
            }
            else if(this.state.value == 'no-edge'){
                this.props.product.options = 0;
            }
            else if(this.state.value == '2inchHemOnly'){
                this.props.product.options = 20;
            }
            else if(this.state.value == '2inchHG'){
                this.props.product.options = 25;
            }
            else if(this.state.value == 'HandG'){
                this.props.product.options = 30;
            }
            else if(this.state.value == 'rope-rail'){
                this.props.product.options = 35;
            }
            else if(this.state.value == 'pole-pocket'){
                this.props.product.options = 40;
            }
        var values = this.props.product.values;
        var options = this.props.product.options;
          api.AddCart(id, this.props.product.quantity)

          .then((options) => {
              console.log(options)
              dispatch({type: "Update_Options", payload: options})
          })
          .then((values) => {
            console.log(values)
            dispatch({type: "Update_Value", payload: values})
          })
          .then((cart) => {
            console.log(cart)
            dispatch({type: "Cart_Updated", gotNew: false})
          })

          .then(() => {
              dispatch({type: "Fetch_Cart_Start", gotNew: false})

              api.GetCartItems()
                
              .then((cart, options, values) => {
                dispatch({type: "Fetch_Cart_End", payload: cart, gotNew: true})
                dispatch({type: "Update_Options", payload: options})
                dispatch({type: "Update_Value", payload: values})
              })
          })
          .then(() => {
              console.error(options)
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e)
          })
        })
      }
      
      addToCart(product.id);
  }
return (
    <main role="main" id="container" className="main-container push">
    <section className="product">
      <div className="content">
          <div className="product-listing">
   
              <div className="product-description">
                  <p className="price"><span className="hide-content">Unit price </span>{'$' + product.meta.display_price.with_tax.amount/100 + this.props.product.options}</p>
                <form className="product" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <label>SELECT EDGING OPTION</label>
                    <select name="edging" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <option value="select">-- Please select --</option>
                            <option value="no-edge">No Edge</option>
                            <option value="2inchHemOnly">2” Hem Only</option>
                            <option value="2inchHG">2” Hem and Grommets 24” On Center</option>
                            <option value="HandG">Hem and Grommets 12” on Center</option>
                    </select>
                    
                        <div className="quantity-input" style={style}>
                            <p className="hide-content">Product quantity.</p>
                            
                           
                        <button type="submit" className="submit">Add to cart</button>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
          
      </section>
      <MailingList />
  </main>
  )
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SingleProduct);
```

And here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
quantity: 1,
options: 0,
values: [
{ value: '-- Please select --' },
{ value: 'No Edge' },
{ value: '2” Hem Only' },
{ value: 'No Edge' },
{ value: '2” Hem and Grommets 24” On Center' },
{ value: 'Hem and Grommets 12” on Center' }
]
}

const ProductReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case "Update_Quantity": {
  return {...state, quantity: action.payload};
}
case "Update_Options": {
  return {...state, 
    options: action.payload};
}
case "Update_Value": {
  return {...state, 
    value: action.payload};
}
default: {
  return {...state};
}
}
};

export default ProductReducer;
```

When I add to the cart my 'value' is undefined. And on refresh, 'options' goes back to 0. My quantity stays in the state though. I just don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The react docs state: Whether you declare a component as a function or a class, it must never modify its own props.

Therefore, you might want to make a copy of the props into a variable and then modify the copy. One way to do this might be to place this line:

```
let propsCopy = { ...this.props }
```

above the line `var addToCart = (id, options) => {`

and then use propsCopy in place of props in the subsequent lines.

Comment: This didn't work. props was undefined above the line var addToCart = (id, options) => {

Comment: My mistake. It should be `let propsCopy = { ...this.props }` just before the point you used this.props the first time. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Just to clarify: In a Component declared as a class the props must be assessed as this.props. (In a functional style component the props are passed in as an argument so may be assessed directly as props).